# Merge two Arrays as JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, dictionary

I have two arrays,

```
Array 1 = [ a, b, c, d]
Array 2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I need to merge them like a dictionary/map (Array 1 is Keys and Array 2 is values) and convert that to JSON.

Below is the converted dictionary/map to JSON and final wanted result.

```
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4"}
```

Comment: You mean JSON & have you tried anything?

Comment: yes JSON, i tried with com.google.gson.Gson

Comment: I don't think GSON is the right way for you to do this because that maps classes to JSON but your structure is dynamic. I'd go with JSON SIMPLE: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples

Comment: From result it looks like you don't want to merge two arrays into one, but you want to create JSON object with keys from first array and values from second array. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As an example of a simple code.

If you have two arrays, lets say Array A and B, just iterate them and create a JSONObject of them, where array A is the keys and array B is the values.

**Basic code example:**

```
JSONObject map = new JSONObject()
for(int i =0; i<array.size(); i++) {
  map.put(arrayA.[i],arrayB[i]);
}
return map;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't want to actually merge two arrays into one, but you want to create JSON object where its keys are stored in first array, and value in second array. In that case you can use [org.json.JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Here is simple example:

```
String[] keys = {"a",  "b",  "c",  "d"};
String[] values = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"};

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
    jsonObject.put(keys[i], values[i]);
}

System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Output `{"a":"aa","b":"bb","c":"cc","d":"dd"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) , and just merge given lists into `Map`

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    Iterator<String> keys = Arrays.asList("a","b").iterator();
    Iterator<String> values = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb").iterator();

    while (keys.hasNext() && values.hasNext()) {
        map.put(keys.next(), values.next());
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all input special thanks to Pshemo. My working code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;


public class ArrayToJason  {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{

        String [] value = {"a", "b" , "c", "d"};
        String [] key = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"};

         Map <String, String> map1 = new HashMap();

            Iterator <String> keys = Arrays.asList(value).iterator();
            Iterator <String> values = Arrays.asList(key).iterator();

            while (keys.hasNext() && values.hasNext()) {
                map1.put(keys.next(), values.next());
            }

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(map1);

                System.out.println("Jason format " + result);

            }catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();


    }
}
}
```

**Jason format {"d":"dd","b":"bb","c":"cc","a":"aa"}

Answer (score 0):

[org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) has a simple way to do it.

```
JSONArray keys = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(array1));
JSONArray values = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(array2));

JSONObject result = values.toJSONObject(keys);
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to convert array into JSON is:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want the following:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    builder.append("\"");
    builder.append(array1[i]);
    builder.append("\":\"");
    builder.append(array2[i]);
    builder.append("\"");
    if (i < (array1.length - 1))
        builder.append(", ");
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Let me try with it. Thanks for quick response